# Merge Image with Video in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, video

Any one know any solution or library which helps to merge an image with video file? I researched some libraries as OpenCV, FFmpeg, but they seem not help my case.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully integrated Ffmpeg in one of my apps and added a watermark image on my video.

These links can be used to compile ffmpeg for Android.

[Link 1](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/)

[Link 2 (better and clearer approach)](http://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/)

Or, if you want to keep away from the hassle you can buy a paid wrapper by indie-developers (although i won't recommend it):

one such example is [ffmpeg4android](http://ffmpeg4android.netcompss.com/)

Comment: i want to add transparent image on video how can i do this?

Comment: @DharaPatel "add image overlay to video ffmpeg" search this on google!

Comment: i have already seen your https://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/ but i didnt get it how to use it

Comment: @DharaPatel it isn't very straightforward to run ffmpeg in Android. I found these 2 relevant links that might be of help to you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMZYJbjxCxQ
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android